# Cast [System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2] to SortedList using reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm trying to compare two objects to each other using reflection to loop through all of their properties. I am geting stuck, however, when trying to compare a SortedList:

**Code**

```
Private Sub CompareObjects(obj1 As Object, obj2 As Object)

            Dim objType1 As Type = obj1.GetType()

            Dim propertyInfo = objType1.GetProperties

            For Each prop As PropertyInfo In propertyInfo
                Dim paramInfo = prop.GetIndexParameters
                If paramInfo.Count > 0 Then Continue For
                If Not prop.CanWrite Then Continue For

                If GetType(SortedList).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) OrElse _
                    prop.PropertyType.Name.ToString.Equals("SortedList`2") Then
                    Dim itemList1 As SortedList = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(obj1), SortedList)
                    Dim itemList2 As SortedList = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(obj2), SortedList)
```

**Error Message** (from Dim itemList1 As SortedList = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(obj1), SortedList))

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[System.String,ANAPLMVC.MyClass]' to type 'System.Collections.SortedList'.

What do I need to do in order to be able to cast these objects into SortedLists so that I can compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.SortedList` is not related to `System.Collections.SortedList` in any way. That cast is not possible. Consider casting to one of these interfaces instead, which are implemented by the generic `SortedList`:

- `System.Collections.IEnumerable`
- `System.Collections.ICollection`
- `System.Collections.IDictionary`